# Scrollview empty space issue

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: How to clear this empty space]

I wanted to create the guideline in my apps,but i found that this empty space is on top of my image, how do i delete it to let my image stay on the top?Below is my layout.xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".InfoActivity">
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/slide1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/slide1"
    android:contentDescription="firstslide" />
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/HELLO"
    android:id="@+id/textView"  />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try to change the layout_height on the scrollview from fill_parent to wrap_content, and basically change all the other fill_parent with match_parent, because fill_parent is the old method

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this in your `ImageView`.

```
android:scaleType="fitStart"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sir, the second problem exist is my text distance different too much with my imageview, any solution? I wanted my text is stay below my image..

Comment: can you show me what exactly you need ? because I cannot really understand you. make a print screen so i can try to help you.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a2ZTwGT after i set it to fitstart, there is so much empty below imageview ,you can see from that link

Comment: `android:layout_below="@+id/slide1"` try this and tell me

Comment: you can also try this in your textview : `android:includeFontPadding="false"`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with android:scaleType="fitXY"